# Returning a whole custom type array from a C++ function

Tags: c++, refactoring, mbed

I am working on a c++ application, to populate a Bluetooth array with some info. It is based on the mbed platforms BLE_API, but I don't think that should be relevant. I have the following code, which I am trying to re-factor into an function.

```
GattAttribute nameDescr1(BLE_UUID_DESCRIPTOR_CHAR_USER_DESC, (uint8_t *)"Percentage", strlen("Percentage"));
GattAttribute *pdescriptors[] = { &nameDescr1 };


  PercentageFill(PercentageUUID, valueBytes.getPointer(),
                   valueBytes.getNumValueBytes(), HeartRateValueBytes::MAX_VALUE_BYTES,
                   GattCharacteristic::BLE_GATT_CHAR_PROPERTIES_NOTIFY | GattCharacteristic::BLE_GATT_CHAR_PROPERTIES_EXTENDED_PROPERTIES,
                   pdescriptors,
                   sizeof(pdescriptors) / sizeof(GattAttribute*)),
```

I have so far got this:

```
   GattAttribute produceName (char title[]) { 
        GattAttribute nameDescr(BLE_UUID_DESCRIPTOR_CHAR_USER_DESC, (uint8_t *)title, strlen(title));
        GattAttribute *descriptors[] = { &nameDescr };
        return descriptors;
    }
```

However, quite predictably I am throwing an error:

> Error: No suitable constructor exists to convert from "GattAttribute *[1]" to "GattAttribute"

I can see why it is throwing this, but am not sure how I should be returning the whole array, as that is the format it is required in by the "PercentageFill" constructor.

Thanks.

## Update:

To give full context, here are the other Characteristcis I am setting up (each with a different name):

```
NewService(BLE &_ble, uint8_t percentageFill, uint8_t replacementDue) :
    ble(_ble),
    valueBytes(percentageFill),
    PercentageFill(PercentageUUID, valueBytes.getPointer(),
                   valueBytes.getNumValueBytes(), HeartRateValueBytes::MAX_VALUE_BYTES,
                   GattCharacteristic::BLE_GATT_CHAR_PROPERTIES_NOTIFY | GattCharacteristic::BLE_GATT_CHAR_PROPERTIES_EXTENDED_PROPERTIES,
                   pdescriptors,
                   sizeof(pdescriptors) / sizeof(GattAttribute*)),
    Time(   TimeUUID,
            &replacementDue,
            GattCharacteristic::BLE_GATT_CHAR_PROPERTIES_NOTIFY | GattCharacteristic::BLE_GATT_CHAR_PROPERTIES_EXTENDED_PROPERTIES,
            tdescriptors,
            sizeof(tdescriptors) / sizeof(GattAttribute*)),
    UseProfile( UseProfileUUID, 
                &controlPointValue,
                GattCharacteristic::BLE_GATT_CHAR_PROPERTIES_NOTIFY | GattCharacteristic::BLE_GATT_CHAR_PROPERTIES_EXTENDED_PROPERTIES,
                Udescriptors,
                sizeof(Udescriptors) / sizeof(GattAttribute*)),) {
                setupService();
}
```

Comment: the error message mentions "constructor" which tells me that you're really programming C++.

Comment: Are you sure you're coding in C?  The error message is more like what a C++ compiler would produce.  In C (and, AFAICR, in C++ too) you cannot return an array from a function.  You can return a pointer (but you can't afford to return a pointer to a local variable).  You could return a structure that contains an array.  But you can't return an array directly.

Comment: Yes, the compiler is C / C++, so it probably is C++, last time I tagged question as C ++, I got down voted - I'll update the question

Comment: That specific problem is: you should be writing code _either_ in C _or_ in C++. If you are writing it in C, you should use a C compiler. If you are writing it in C++, you should use a C++ compiler. Not rocket science.

Comment: @Lundin I am using the mbed online IDE and hardware platform, which doesn't seem to make the distinction.

Comment: @GeorgeEdwards Seems like it is a C++ compiler by Keil. If you need to write C code, you should either figure out how to configure it to compile C or get a new compiler. Keil aren't exactly famous for standard compliance...

Comment: @Lundin I think I'll just code it in C++ then?

Comment: @Lundin Any ideas how this could work?

Comment: @GeorgeEdwards How what could work, your code? It shows several fundamental misunderstandings about how pointers and memory allocation work. You need to read up on the basics in your favourite C++ book before you do anything else.

Comment: @GeorgeEdwards If you understood the basics you wouldn't declare a local variable and then attempt to return a pointer to it, nor would you attempt to return an array from a function. Instead, simply pass the array as a parameter and modify it. Or alternatively, use std::vector.

Answer (score 2):

The function is `produceName` is declare to return an `GattAttribute` object, but you are trying to return an array of pointers to `GattAttribute` objects. Quite a difference.

But that's not the worst part of your code. If you fix the declaration return type so the code builds, you have an even worse problem that will lead to *undefined behavior*: You return pointers to local variables. Once the function returns, those local variables will cease to exist, and any pointer to them can't be used.

Comment: `nameDescr` is a variable?

Comment: What would you suggest is a better approach?

Comment: @SouravGhosh `nameDescr` is indeed a `GattAttribute` object

Comment: @GeorgeEdwards How about just `return nameDescr;`? Or, no need for the temporary variable at all, just do `return GattAttribute(BLE_UUID_DESCRIPTOR_CHAR_USER_DESC, (uint8_t *)title, strlen(title));`

Comment: @JoachimPileborg that throws the compiler Error: `"GattAttribute::GattAttribute(const GattAttribute &)" (declared at <a href="#" onmousedown="mbed_doc_goto('/BLE_HeartRate/BLE_API/ble/GattAttribute.h', '75'); return false;">BLE_API/ble/GattAttribute.h:75</a>) is inaccessible` I am using a standard API Library and it would be great to have a solution which is compatible with that. [Here](https://developer.mbed.org/teams/Bluetooth-Low-Energy/code/BLE_API/file/a097e1be76f4/ble/GattAttribute.h) is the doc it is referring to.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: note that the `pdescriptors` array in the original code is only *one* element long. So a straight pointer to object will work just fine, or it would if the percentage fill didn't expect an array of pointers. We can mimic this by passing a pointer-to-pointer and a size of 1. Do note: the `sizeof(...)/sizeof(...)` calculation in the original code is also meant to return 1 and this gets tricky when you introduce function boundaries (specifically when you pass the array as argument to a function).

Beyond that your question is somewhat unclear: do you intend for different `GattAttribute` values to be possible? If not, you probably could do something like:

```
void updatePercentage(WhateverTypeValueBytesIs valueBytes) {
    GattAttribute nameDescr(BLE_UUID_DESCRIPTOR_CHAR_USER_DESC, (uint8_t *)"Percentage", strlen("Percentage"));
    GattAttribute * ptr = &nameDescr; // needed, because we want to pass pointer-to-pointer-to-nameDescr
    PercentageFill(PercentageUUID, valueBytes.getPointer(),
               valueBytes.getNumValueBytes(), HeartRateValueBytes::MAX_VALUE_BYTES,
               GattCharacteristic::BLE_GATT_CHAR_PROPERTIES_NOTIFY | GattCharacteristic::BLE_GATT_CHAR_PROPERTIES_EXTENDED_PROPERTIES,
               &ptr, 1), /* are we sure about trailing comma here? */
    // other relevant trailing code?
}
```

Judging by the error message about an inaccessible copy-constructor you mentioned in the comments, `GattAttribute` is probably a regular constructor so there's no need to create additional functions there. If you want to turn this particular `GattAttribute` into something you can hide behind a function interface and 'look up' when desired, then you can turn it into a singleton like this (for example, other ways to achieve the same objective exist):

```
GattAttribute * getNameDescriptor(void) {
    static GattAttribute nameDescr(BLE_UUID_DESCRIPTOR_CHAR_USER_DESC, (uint8_t *)"Percentage", strlen("Percentage"));
    return &nameDescr;
}
```

Then you can use that function like this:

```
void updatePercentage(WhateverTypeValueBytesIs valueBytes) {
    GattAttribute * ptr = getNameDescriptor(); // needed, because we want to pass pointer-to-pointer-to-nameDescr
    PercentageFill(PercentageUUID, valueBytes.getPointer(),
               valueBytes.getNumValueBytes(), HeartRateValueBytes::MAX_VALUE_BYTES,
               GattCharacteristic::BLE_GATT_CHAR_PROPERTIES_NOTIFY | GattCharacteristic::BLE_GATT_CHAR_PROPERTIES_EXTENDED_PROPERTIES,
               &ptr, 1), /* are we sure about trailing comma here? */
    // other relevant trailing code?
}
```

EDIT to add additional option(s) based on comments:

```
void updatePercentage(WhateverTypeValueBytesIs valueBytes, const char* name) {
    GattAttribute nameDescr(BLE_UUID_DESCRIPTOR_CHAR_USER_DESC, (const uint8_t *) name, strlen(name));
    GattAttribute * ptr = &nameDescr; // needed, because we want to pass pointer-to-pointer-to-nameDescr
    PercentageFill(PercentageUUID, valueBytes.getPointer(),
               valueBytes.getNumValueBytes(), HeartRateValueBytes::MAX_VALUE_BYTES,
               GattCharacteristic::BLE_GATT_CHAR_PROPERTIES_NOTIFY | GattCharacteristic::BLE_GATT_CHAR_PROPERTIES_EXTENDED_PROPERTIES,
               &ptr, 1), /* are we sure about trailing comma here? */
    // other relevant trailing code?
}
```

Or another option: trivial, pass in a fully initialised `GattAttribute` by reference:

```
void updatePercentage(WhateverTypeValueBytesIs valueBytes, GattAttribute & descr) {
    GattAttribute * ptr = &descr; // needed, because we want to pass pointer-to-pointer-to-descr
    PercentageFill(PercentageUUID, valueBytes.getPointer(),
               valueBytes.getNumValueBytes(), HeartRateValueBytes::MAX_VALUE_BYTES,
               GattCharacteristic::BLE_GATT_CHAR_PROPERTIES_NOTIFY | GattCharacteristic::BLE_GATT_CHAR_PROPERTIES_EXTENDED_PROPERTIES,
               &ptr, 1), /* are we sure about trailing comma here? */
    // other relevant trailing code?
}
```

Which you call like this:

```
void foo(WhateverTypeValueBytesIs valueBytes) {
    GattAttribute nameDescr(BLE_UUID_DESCRIPTOR_CHAR_USER_DESC, (uint8_t *)"Percentage", strlen("Percentage"));
    updatePercentage(valueBytes, nameDescr);
}
```

Obviously, instead of using references you could also rework the function to take a pointer to a `GattAttribute` object (and use that instead of the `ptr` variable the same way the `ptr` variable is used in the examples).

A further addition: note that you probably want to avoid copying `valueBytes` when you pass it to `updatePercentage`, and here you probably want to pass it by reference.

Comment: Thanks for this. You have asked a few questions, re: trailing code etc. After percentage fill, there are a few other Characteristics to be set up, with different names, hence the trailing comma and desire to make this code reusable. So ideally, I would like to be able to pass the string descriptor to the function and for it to return the array for that string, if that makes sense?

Comment: Is there anyway I can structure what you have put, to work for various different names?

Comment: @GeorgeEdwards obviously you can take the first option, and modify it so `updatePercentage` takes additional `const char* name` argument and uses that instead of the hardcoded `"Percentage"` value...

Comment: Added a few more options. I think you should probably take the time to read up on how functions work in C++, specifically about passing things by value, by reference and using pointers (as in- or as out- arguments).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't phrase the problem properly. I do understand the principle of what we are doing (although I am new to it). But I need to be able to construct multiple different named constructors in `updatePercentage` Please see my question update.

Comment: Ideally, in the Characteristic constructors shown above (i.e. PecentageFill), I would like to be able to call descriptors("Percentage") etc. for each of the Characteristics with a different string each time. It looks as though it should be simple, but I am not able to make it work.